# mysql - order by field not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

suppose I've a database , the table contains rows with ides from 1 to 20 .

i want to return 3 rows with id 3,4,1 first and then return the other rows . this is my code :

```
    SELECT id
FROM prod
ORDER BY field( id, 3, 4, 1 ) 
LIMIT 20
```

this is the result of this code :

```
id
13 
17 
16 
15 
 7 
 6 
 5 
 2 
 3 
 4 
 1
```

strangely the 3 rows that I need to come first are showing at the end ,

How can I bring these 3 rows to the top of the list ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `DESC`:

```
SELECT id
FROM prod
ORDER BY field( id, 3, 4, 1 ) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

The issue is that MySQL puts `NULL` values first when you do an ascending order by.

If you actually want the rows in the order 3, 4, 1, then reverse them in the `field` statement:

```
SELECT id
FROM prod
ORDER BY field( id, 1, 4, 3 ) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Or, if you wanted to be fancy:

```
ORDER BY - field( id, 3, 4, 1 ) DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

The other way is to use `case-when` and giving each `id` an `order value`

```
select * from prod 
order by 
case 
  when id = 3 then 0  
  when id=4 then 1 
  when id=1 then 2 
  else 3 
end,id 
limit 20
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `DESC`

```
SELECT id
FROM prod
ORDER BY field( id, 3, 4, 1 ) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

It seems your id order is important. Reverse numbers to get correct result

```
SELECT id
FROM prod
ORDER BY field( id, 1, 4, 3 ) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try

```
SELECT id,
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN id = '3' THEN 0 
                WHEN id = '4' THEN 1 
                WHEN id = '1' THEN 2
            END
        ) as rank 
        FROM prod  
        ORDER BY rank
        LIMIT 20;
```